# Best choice for a huge database table which contains only integers (have to use SUM() or AVG() )

Tags: database, integer, scalability, sum, average

I'm currently using a MySQL table for an online game under LAMP.

One of the table is huge (soon millions of rows) and contains only integers (IDs,timestamps,booleans,scores).

I did everything to never have to JOIN on this table. However, I'm worried about the scalability. I'm thinking about moving this single table to another faster database system.
I use intermediary tables to calculate the scores but in some cases, I have to use SUM() or AVERAGE() directly on some filtered rowsets of this table.

For you, what is the best database choice for this table?

My requirements/specs:

- This table contains only integers (around 15 columns)
- I need to filter by certain columns
- I'd like to have UNIQUE KEYS
- It could be nice to have "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE UPDATE" but I suppose my scripts can manage it by themselves.
- i have to use SUM() or AVERAGE()

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure you have the correct indexes on so selecting should be quick

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. So you think MySQL is able to easily manage this kind of table and SQL functions.

Comment: Yeh, assuming you have the correct indexes. A properly indexed huge table should still be fast to lookup. Put a clustered index on the field your going to put in the where clasuse http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_%28database%29

Comment: Almost every fields will be in where clause in some case or others. I already put indexes on some of them. I have to check the consequences of creating to much indexes

Answer (score 0):

Millions of rows in a table isn't huge. You shouldn't expect any problems in selecting, filtering or upserting data if you index on relevant keys as @Tom-Squires suggests.

Aggregate queries (sum and avg) may pose a problem though. The reason is that they require a full table scan and thus multiple fetches of data from disk to memory. A couple of methods to increase their speed:

1. If your data changes infrequently then caching those query results in your code is probably a good solution.
2. If it changes frequently  then the quickest way to improve their performance is probably to ensure that your database engine keeps the table in memory. A quick calculation of expected size: 15 columns x 8 bytes x millions =~ 100's of MB - not really an issue (unless you're on a shared host). If your RDBMS does not support tuning this for a specific table, then simply put it in a different database schema - shouldn't be a problem since you're not doing any joins on this table. Most engines will allow you to tune that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's really helpful. I suppose the memory is not a problem. The database is hosted in a cloud hosting service where i can easily change the properties of the servers.